# Overlaying text on an image and uploading to server

Tags: php, html, css

I am new to PHP and struggling with adding text overlay to an image before uploading it to the server. This is my current function but its not adding the text into the image.

```
function image_file_upload($conn) {
$target_dir = "../users/images/";
$caption = $_POST['comment'];
$imgFile = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
$tmp_dir = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($imgFile);
$uploadOk = 1;
$font_color = bcca;
$background_color = abbc;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$ext = explode('.',$imgFile);
$file = $target_dir . uniqid() . "." . $ext[1];
$uid = 4;
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

$check = getimagesize($tmp_dir);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir, $file)) {

                $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);
                $font_path = 'simple.ttf';
                $text = "This is a Sunset!";
                imagettftext($jpg_image, 10, 0, 0, 0, $white, $font_path, $text);
                imagejpeg($jpg_image,$file);

       $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
       insert_into_post($conn, $uid, 1, $date, $file, $background_color, $font_color, 0 , 0, "image", $caption);
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps missed in your code. Check out the commented code below and see if it does what you want:

```
    <?php
        function image_file_upload($conn) {
            // IF WE THERE WAS NO FILE UPLOADED, WE JUST REPORT THAT AND TERMINATE THE FUNCTION IMMEDIATELY:
            if(!isset($_FILES['user_image']) && empty($_FILES['user_image'])){
                echo "Please, upload a File using the Form....";
                return null;                    
            }

            $target_dir         = "../users/images/";
            $caption            = $_POST['comment'];
            $imgFile            = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
            $tmp_dir            = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];
            $target_file        = $target_dir . basename($imgFile);
            $font_color         = "#bcca00";      //<== YOUR COLOR SHOULD BE A VALID HEX OR RGB OR HSLA COLOR VALUE
            $background_color   = "#abbc00";      //<== YOUR COLOR SHOULD BE A VALID HEX OR RGB OR HSLA COLOR VALUE
            $fileInfo           = new SplFileInfo($imgFile);
            $ext                = $fileInfo->getExtension();
            $file               = $target_dir . uniqid() . "." . $ext;
            $uid                = 4;
            $check              = getimagesize($tmp_dir);

            // CHECK THAT getimagesize RETURNS AN ARRAY OF DATA
            if(!empty($check)){                 
                // CHECK THAT THIS WAS AN IMAGE FILE USING THE MIME PROPERTY OF THE $check ARRAY...
                if (stristr($check['mime'], "image/")) {
                    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir, $file)) {
                        // GRAB A COPY OF THE UPLOADED IMAGE - SO THAT WE CAN ADD TEXT TO IT...
                        $jpg_image  = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                        $white      = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);
                        $red        = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 0, 0); //<== RED: JUST FOR TESTING PURPOSES...
                        $font_path  = 'simple.ttf';
                        $text       = "This is a Sunset!";
                        $date       = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                        // ADD TEXT TO THE IMAGE... BE CAREFUL WITH THE X, Y  LOCATION...
                        // YOU MAY NEED TO PLAY AROUND WITH IT A BIT ESPECIALLY CONSIDERING THE FONT-SIZE...
                        imagettftext($jpg_image, 50, 0, 50, 50, $red, $font_path, $text);

                        // SAVE BACK THE IMAGE WITH SOME TEXT SUPERIMPOSED ON IT...
                        imagejpeg($jpg_image, $file);

                        // INSERT SOME DATA RELATED TO THE UPLOADED IMAGE TO THE DATABASE...
                        insert_into_post($conn, $uid, 1, $date, $file, $background_color, $font_color, 0, 0, "image", $caption);
                    }else {
                        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
                    }
                }else {
                    echo "File is not an image.";
                }
            }

        }

        // CHECK THAT THE FORM WAS SUBMITTED BEFORE RUNNING THE UPLOAD PROCESS...
        if(isset($_POST["upload"])){
            image_file_upload($connectionHandle);
        }

        ?>

    <html>

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
        <input type="file" name="user_image" value="" id="user_image" /><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload" id="upload" />
    </form>
    </html>
```